# How to add new dialog on workflow transition in Jira

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to make a jira plugin that works like a workflow validator, but instead of not allowing a transition if certain conditions are not met, I want to just bring up a warning dialog where the user can choose to continue or cancel the transition.

As far as I can tell this is not possible using a workflow validator, as that will only bring up an error if the conditions are not met.

I have written webwork plugins before, and that would seem like one likely possibility, but I don't know how it would be possible to intercept the workflow transition to perform the custom action.

I don't know if what I want to do is possible at all, and if it is, I don't know if a webwork plugin would be able to do it.

Are there any Jira experts out there who could point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Marcus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those popup windows are called screens. You should create a new screen and attach it to your transition of workflow. Add a custom field of type (if I remember correctly) "Velocity processed Message Custom Field (for edit)", and add default value your message, that contains something like "If you want to continue transition, push button, if you don't want, push Cancel in corner".

You could also use a JavaScript snippet, added to some field description, that would add into that specific workflow popup window more text, style it, etc.